# How can I turn off optimizations for a certain folder in Eclipse?

Tags: c, gcc, eclipse-cdt, compiler-optimization

I am trying to turn off optimizations for the contents of a single project folder. The project is currently using optimization level -O3.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Used tools:

1. GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors (arm-none-eabi-gcc)
   gcc version 5.4.1 20160919 (release)
2. Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
   Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)
   Build id: 20161208-0600

Edit:
I have an automatically generated makefile for each sub-directory. 
Example.

```
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!


# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 
C_SRCS += \
../App/src/CustomerUnit.c \

OBJS += \
../App/src/CustomerUnit.o \

C_DEPS += \
../App/src/CustomerUnit.d \

# Each subdirectory must supply rules for building sources it contributes
ahuapp/Diagnostics/cag/%.o: ../App/src/%.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: Cross ARM GNU C Compiler'
    arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -O3 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -g3 -D$(M3AppSymbols) -I"../$(M3APPIncludePaths)" -std=gnu11 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -c -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '
```

So what I want to do, that I don't know, is change the -O3 level to -O0 only for this particular sub directory.

Comment: You will have to write a proper makefile.

Comment: By the way, it is very likely an XY-problem. You don't usually want to turn optimizations off, but you might think it is going to solve some undefined behavior.

Comment: I think that my X problem is that if I turn of optimizations, for the whole project, I run out of memory. This is the reason why I want to turn optimizations off in just one sub-directory. Do you think I should ask How to avoid running out of memory? even though I think it's a broad question.

Comment: Old question, but in my case, I need to debug a function in the given file. Turning `-O0` for the whole project makes me short of memory, while enabling them makes the debugger jump all over the place while debugging.